# self.view.bounds not working in portrait view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a fullscreen scroll view. I'm loading two images into it. Works fine in Landscape mode, however in Portrait mode the images are bigger than the screen so I can only see a part of them. It appears that self.view.bounds doesn't provide the right screen size

```
 CGRect frameForView1 = self.view.bounds;
 CGRect frameForView2 = self.view.bounds;

 image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath]];
 [image1 setFrame:frameForView1];
 [self.scrollView addSubview:image1];
 [image1 release];

 frameForView2.origin.x = frameForView2.size.width;
 image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath]];
 [image2 setFrame:frameForView2];
 [self.scrollView addSubview:image2];
 [image2 release];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, you should check what orientation the screen is in and hardwire the known view values for the given orientation.

```
BOOL isLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation);
if(isLandscape)
    //do something with landscape frame values
else(doSomethingElse)
    //do something with portrait frame values
```

Comment: `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` doesn't change with rotation, but a view controller's view's bounds do. (assuming default behavior, i.e. standard auto resizing masks)